# What is the point of invbool in C kernel programming?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, boolean

I'm beginning to do a bit more kernel programming, and in reading, found the existence of `invbool`. However, I can't seem to find anything on the Internet about it, except for the documented definition, copied nearly verbatim in a few places:

> The invbool type inverts the value, so that true values become false and vice versa.

Thinking about this, I can't think of an instance where this would make code less confusing. Is there a good example of when you would use this? Why does it only seem to come up in kernel programming documentation?

Comment: You aren't the only one: https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/kernel-janitors/2007-May/018896.html Looks like some legacy of bad design decision.

Comment: Linux kernel code is riddled with old, undocumented and seemingly useless code. This is just a very simple example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `invbool` functions are used in parsing kernel command lines and module options.  The `bool` versions parse an option which the user can set as `0/1` or `N/Y` or `off/on`, and set a `bool` flag accordingly.  The `invbool` versions apply a `!` to the result, so `Y` maps to `false` and `N` maps to `true`.

As far as I can tell, their only purpose is for convenience or "clarity" when the programmer wants to have an internal flag with the opposite sense from the user's configuration parameter.  For instance, maybe it makes more sense from the user's perspective to be able to set a flag to disable the foo option (because it should be enabled by default), but from the kernel programmer's perspective it is more convenient to have a flag that simply says whether foo is enabled.  You could then have a user-set parameter called `disable_foo` and an internal boolean flag called `foo_is_enabled`.  You want `foo_is_enabled = false` when the user specifies `disable_foo=Y`, so you could use `invbool` here.

You can see something like this happening in [aty128fb.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/93b694d096cc10994c817730d4d50288f9ae3d66/drivers/video/fbdev/aty/aty128fb.c#L2523): the user can set the `nomtrr` parameter to disable the use of the memory type range registers, but the programmer preferred to have a boolean variable `mtrr` that is `true` if MTRRs are enabled.

You might think these are redundant because you could just do `mtrr = !parameter_bool("nomtrr")`, but in fact the `param_set_*` functions return the parameter values by reference instead of by value, so you can't so easily just plop a `!` into the expression.

I suspect the thought was that defining these functions made such code more "self-documenting".  This is of course debatable.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that the parameter values are passed by reference instead of by value. I was wondering why you wouldn't just invert the bool yourself, so that helps to shine a little light on that madness